# Write to local text file on a mac with mono and c#

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm trying to write to a log file on a mac in the app's folder. I'm currently using Mono. I've read this is problematic with StreamWriter. Does anyone have a better solution?

```
private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt");
    writer.WriteLine("File created using StreamWriter class.");
    writer.Close();  
}
```

Comment: `I've read this is problematic with StreamWriter` Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: Note that the current directory is not the same as the directories that may contain your EXE or DLL.

Comment: So... how do you write to the local directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the directory containing your assembly by calling

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SomeType).Assembly.Location)
```

You can then add get a path to a filename in that directory by calling `Path.Combine()`.